# Abstract Classes error

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a problem with my program and I can't find the reason why thought. It points at the `public static void main(String[] args)` line nowhere else, can't figure it out :(
Tried checking for the braces, if by accident I missed one or two but still no, it is not an interface implementation so I don't have to set each method of the abstract class to public in the implementation...

```
abstract class Shape {

private String name;

Shape(String name0) {name = name0;}

abstract double area(); 

abstract double perim();

void put() { 
    System.out.println(name + " with area " + area()+ " and perimeter " + perim());
   }
}

class Circle extends Shape{
private double r;

Circle(String name0, double inR) {
    super(name0);
    r = inR;
}

double area() {
    return (Math.sqrt(r)*Math.PI);
}

double perim() {
    return 2*(Math.PI * r);
}   
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{
private double a,b;

Rectangle(String name0, double a0, double b0) {
    super(name0);
    a=a0; b=b0;
}

double area() {
    return (a*b);
}

double perim() {
    return 2*(a+b);
}
}

}

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


    Shape[] figures = {new Rectangle("Rectangle", 2.0, 3.0), new Rectangle("Square", 4.0, 4.0), new Circle("Circle", 2.0)};
    for (Shape s: figures) 
            s.put();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra closing brace `}` before the main method. Just remove that.

**Suggestion:** It is really wise to use an IDE to do coding because you can get away from these compilation errors easily and quickly.

Comment: I use eclipse and it didn't find it :( And now that I look on this code i feel like the class Rectangle is not closed, don't know why :(

Comment: Some weird things happened :D It fixed the problem as you sudgested but something's wrong and I can't see the last brace of the Rectangle class but it works :P So I don't mind haha Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski Accept the answer in case it helped.